# Crear archivo WAR aplicación JS

Tags: html, netbeans, jsp, tomcat, war

alguien sabría los pasos para crear un archivo WAR desde Netbeans?

Quiero desplegarlo desde Tomcat y he buscado diferentes formas en Google para generar el archivo .war pero no funciona :/

Si alguien lo ha creado alguna vez y me lo explica se lo agradecería

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Has visto dentro de las carpetas donde se genera el proyecto?

Comment: Ya esta generado el WAR gracias

Comment: En la parte inferior, hay un text area donde dice "Tu Respuesta", sería bueno que agregues lo que realizaste para obtener dicho archivo, serás el héroe de más usuarios con la misma situación :D

Comment: Encima de tu proyecto Netbeans, clicas botón derecho > Clean and Build

Comment: Creo que no me dejé entender, revisa este par de enlaces: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask del mismo modo, aquí tienes los ingredientes de una buena respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y bueno, realiza un scrolling hasta el fondo de la página actual, verás un botón que dice "Publica tu respuesta", y arriba de ese botón, un textarea para que coloques la respuesta que ha sido de utilidad :D